# How to Remove Every Other Element in an Array in Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift

So say I have an array:

```
var stringArray = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j"]
```

Now, how do I delete "a", "c", "e", "g", and "i" (all the even number indexes from the array)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 17):

Instead of using C-style for-loops (which are set to be deprecated in an upcoming version of Swift), you could accomplish this using strides:

```
var result = [String]()
for i in stride(from: 1, through: stringArray.count - 1, by: 2) {
    result.append(stringArray[i])
}
```

Or for an even more functional solution,

```
let result = stride(from: 1, to: stringArray.count - 1, by: 2).map { stringArray[$0] }
```

Comment: Value of type 'Int' has no member 'stride'

Comment: It's a global function now. See documentation here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/1641347-stride.

The code should look something like this instead:
`let result = stride(from: 1, through: stringArray.count - 1, by: 2).map { stringArray[$0] }`

Answer (score 10):

**Traditional**

```
var filteredArray = []
for var i = 1; i < stringArray.count; i = i + 2 {
    filteredArray.append(stringArray[i])
}
```

**Functional alternative**

```
var result = stringArray.enumerate().filter({ index, _ in
    index % 2 != 0
}).map { $0.1 }
```

`enumerate` takes a array of elements and returns an array of tuples where each tuple is an index-array pair (e.g. `(.0 3, .1 "d")`). We then remove the elements that are odd using the modulus operator. Finally, we convert the tuple array back to a normal array using `map`. HTH

Answer (score 3):

There are a bunch of different ways to accomplish this, but here are a couple that I found interesting:

Using `flatMap()` on `indices`:

```
let result: [String] = stringArray.indices.flatMap {
    if $0 % 2 != 0 { return stringArray[$0] }
    else { return nil }
}
```

***Note:** `result` needs to be defined as a `[String]` otherwise the compiler doesn't know which version of `flatMap()` to use.*

Or, if you want to modify the original array in place:

```
stringArray.indices.reverse().forEach {
    if $0 % 2 == 0 { stringArray.removeAtIndex($0) }
}
```

In this case you have to call `reverse()` on `indices` first so that they're enumerated in reverse order. Otherwise by the time you get to the end of the array you'll be attempting to remove an index that doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: Note, remove at index is really expensive when removing throughout the whole array like this.

Answer (score 1):

### Swift 4.2

A function accepting generics and producing reduced result

```
func stripElements<T>(in array:[T]) -> [T] {
    return array.enumerated().filter { (arg0) -> Bool in
        let (offset, _) = arg0
        return offset % 2 != 0
        }.map { $0.element }
}
```